# Bass Boost - JDA Lavaplayer

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda, lavaplayer

How would you create a bass boost command when you are using Lavaplayer with JDA (Java Discord API)?

Have a command like `!bassboost 0-100`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of trying different things to get it to function correctly I ended up using a Lavaplayer EqualizerFactory.

Firstly I copied these values from [here](https://github.com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer/blob/master/testbot/src/main/java/com/sedmelluq/discord/lavaplayer/demo/music/MusicController.java#L40-L41)

```java
    public static final float[] BASS_BOOST = {
            0.2f,
            0.15f,
            0.1f,
            0.05f,
            0.0f,
            -0.05f,
            -0.1f,
            -0.1f,
            -0.1f,
            -0.1f,
            -0.1f,
            -0.1f,
            -0.1f,
            -0.1f,
            -0.1f
    };
```

then I created a new EqualizerFactory and added it as a filter to the guild music manager and also set the frame buffer duration to make the bass-boost take less time to take effect like so:

```java
        this.equalizer = new EqualizerFactory();

        this.player.setFilterFactory(equalizer);
        this.player.setFrameBufferDuration(500); // prevent bass boost taking time to take effect
```

then I finally created a little method that you can provide from 0-200 to set the bass-boost level

```java
    public void bassBoost(float percentage)
    {
        final float multiplier = percentage / 100.00f;

        for (int i = 0; i < BASS_BOOST.length; i++)
        {
            equalizer.setGain(i, BASS_BOOST[i] * multiplier);
        }
    }
```

so that the bass-boost took effect on the current playing song I needed this:

```java
playerManager.getConfiguration().setFilterHotSwapEnabled(true);
```

and that's about it really!